# How to prove that $1^2+2^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ with a combinatorial proof

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Prove that $1^2+2^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ by using only Double Counting.

(Hint: Count the triples of $(x,y,z)$ for some conditions)

I can only prove the left side.

Comment: Can you show your work? You said "I can only prove the left side".

Comment: You should, at the very least, give the conditions on the triples that allow you to establish the LHS.

Comment: What does "I can only prove the left side" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very elegant (but long) proof which deals with counting the elements of the set
$$T_n=\{(a,b,c)\in S_n:a<c,\,b<c\}$$
where
$$S_n=\{1,2,3,\dots ,n,n+1\}$$
The idea is to first fix $c$ and choose $a$ and $b$ keeping the conditions in mind. This gives the expression
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$
And then try to use the fact that in a triple, either $a=b$ or $a\neq b$. this will give you the RHS.

You can find the details [here](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/020/10/0880-0892).

Comment: Thank you. In fact, they gave this question with 1 page to write the solution.